# Is there any way to setup maintanance page on loadbalancer if there is no ec2 added in LB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is there any way to setup custom maintenance page on AWS Classic load balancer if there is no EC2 are running under LB. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS load balancer and maintenance page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343136/aws-load-balancer-and-maintenance-page)

Comment: For ELB Classic: without EC2 instances - no, all the options are listed in the question I linked.